# Is it possible to retrieve a file removed using file.remove?

Tags: windows, r, recovery, data-recovery

I foolishly ran the following code

```
file.remove(list.files())
```

Is there any way of retrieving the deleted files. I am working in windows XP + R  2.15.0

Comment: Could you be more specific? I do not understand what you did and what you would like to retrieve.

Comment: within the  R console I ran the code `file.remove(list.files())` which deleted all the files within my working directory. I was wondering If there was a way to 'un-remove' them.

Comment: If they are not in the trashcan I am afraid they are lost, but maybe some Windows expert know some trick I do not know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get a NTFS (or FAT32, though unlikely) file recovery software. Restoration and Undelete Plus are a few of them